# Maximal interval $(T_{min}, T_{max})$ of definition for the solution of an ODE: definition

Tags: abstract-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I would like to know the definition of Maximal interval $(T_{min}, T_{max})$ of definition for the solution of an ODE.

My professor defines the $T_{max}$ as follows:

$T_{max} $ = sup{t > t_0 such that the local solution of the CP-ODE admits a right continuation}.

But he does not define the $T_{min} $.

Is the following correct?

$T_{max} $ = inf{t < t_0 such that the local solution of the CP-ODE admits a left continuation}..

Comment: Your definition of $T_{\max}$ is not correct *unless* you know that the solution is unique. The same comment applies to your definition of $T_{\min}$.

Comment: Assume we know the solution is unique. Are my definition of tmax and tmin correct?

Comment: Then yes.------